# iOS Gradient and UIColors

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradient, uicolor, ios7

I have the following code, but am missing how to get my UIColor * into the gradient.colors array:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.view.frame;

UIColor *lightGreen = [UIColor colorWithRed:66.0f/255.0f green:79.0f/255.0f blue:91.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
UIColor *darkGreen = [UIColor colorWithRed:66.0f/255.0f green:79.0f/255.0f blue:91.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor], (id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor]CGColor], nil];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

Comment: Your example works for me. Maybe there is a problem on the second line, where You should assign self.view.bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way, following the Apple sample. It is for overriding drawRect on a UIView. Not very abstracted, but it works.

```
CGGradientRef myGradient;
CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace;
size_t num_locations = 2;
CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

CGFloat comps[8];
const CGFloat *start = CGColorGetComponents(startColor.CGColor);
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    comps[i] = start[i];
}
const CGFloat *end = CGColorGetComponents(endColor.CGColor);
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    comps[i+4] = end[i];
}   

myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, comps,
        locations, num_locations);
```

For the simple task of adding `CGColorRef` objects to an array:

```
CGColorRef colorArray[2] = { lightGreen.CGColor, darkGreen.CGColor };
```

Comment: is there no way to get a UIColor pointer passed into the gradient.colors array?

Comment: I added the appropriate line. It is really the same syntax as demonstrated above.